# Where to find info on ODBC SQL dialect/grammar, incl. built-in functions/operators?

Tags: sql, database, reference, odbc, grammar

I'm looking into writing a C++ database library that will run on top of either ODBC or on top of another library that itself uses ODBC (possibly DTL, OTL, or SOCI).  At this point I need to know what SQL functions (MIN, MAX, AVG, EXISTS, IN, etc.) and operators (+, -, /, *, etc.) I'll have available through the ODBC SQL dialect without needing to do anything vendor-specific.  I assume some or all of those details will depend on driver compliance level, but this is my first time digging into anything ODBC-specific, so I'm a little lost.  Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this post, I found the following:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.programmer.doc/doc/s0005303.sql.minimum.grammar.html

Any other resources for this type of info are most welcome.